# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE S_6500_67_SNAPSHOT_ROWDATA_201([MATERIAL] varchar2(2000), [OBJVERS] varchar2(2000), [CHANGED] varchar2(2000), [AF_COLOR] varchar2(2000), [AF_FCOCO] varchar2(2000), [AF_GENDER] varchar2(2000), [PROD_HIER] varchar2(2000),  [WIDTH] decimal)
```

when i run the above query i get the exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: Does Oracle understand those square brackets? ANSI SQL has double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"MATERIAL"`.

Comment: get rid of the `[ ]` from the column names.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for creating table in Oracle is

```
  CREATE TABLE table_name
( 
  column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  ...
  column_n datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ]
);
```

So, just remove the square brackets from column name and I think you should write your query as follows

```
CREATE TABLE S_6500_67_SNAPSHOT_ROWDATA_201(MATERIAL varchar2(2000), OBJVERS varchar2(2000), CHANGED varchar2(2000), AF_COLOR varchar2(2000), AF_FCOCO varchar2(2000), AF_GENDER varchar2(2000), PROD_HIER varchar2(2000),  WIDTH decimal)
```